# WPF Work-In-Progress animation not displaying for data binding updates

Tags: wpf, data-binding, progress

I have a helper class I've written which can be used to run a long running task on my GUI. What it does is use styles to display a "working" animation and fades out the content so while the task is running, the user can see that something is in progress.

My problem is that when the long running task completes, it fades the content back in and hides the working animation - which is what it should do, but because I am using MVVM and primarily data binding for all my content display, the updates to the GUI components happen separately to the long running task. ie the data binding OnPropertyChanged("") events fire and then these are picked up by the GUI thread AFTER the long running task completes. But the problem is the Worker Animation closes when the long running task completes, but BEFORE the data bindings update.

So the end result is you get the worker animation displaying as expected while the task runs, but the data binding update takes a good 4-5 seconds or even longer for large datasets for all the tree data and during this time, the application is not in "working animation mode" and just freezes.

Is there a way I can have my worker animation continue to run not only for the Long running Method, but for the associated data binding updates from OnPropertyChanged as well?

Comment: Did you try calling the NotifyPropertyChanged method when your long running method completes the work?

Comment: The long running method goes through and updates a lot of ViewModel objects, lots of properties. In the Setter for each of the properties I am calling OnPropertyChanged(), so these are all getting called before the long running method completes as they are part of it. Is that the method you meant? I'm not sure the inner workings of INotifyPropertyChanged but based on the observed behaviour, I'm guessing INotifyPropertyChanged sends the call to the GUI dispatcher thread, which then queues up along with all subsequent ones, until the long running work completes and the GUI thread frees up?

Comment: Are you executing your long running task?  On a separate thread, background worker, etc.?  Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home) from Extended WPF toolkit. It should provide functionality you described. It has IsBusy property which you can bind to property in your ViewModel and set it to *False* after all work is done. 
You can always change the style of BusyIndicator same way as you do with other controls. In my solutions I always use this control along with BackgroundWorker class from *System.ComponentModel* and I usually set          *IsBusy=false* at the end of *RunWorkerCompleted*

```
    private void LongRunningMethod()
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += this.LongMethodDoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void LongMethodDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        ...
    }

    private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        ...
        this.IsBusy = false;
    }
```

Comment: That still won't solve his problem as he wants the Animation to finish only after the BINDINGS have finished and not after the long task has finished

Comment: In that way I am sorry for wrong answer... and I will wait for someone who answers and explains how you can find out that bindings have "finished". And what I understood from authors comment his GUI thread is freezed? It's not the problem with BackgroundWorker. Am I wrong again?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers. I've actually come across a solution that may be a bit controversial as some would construe it is a little bit of a hack, but it does exactly what I want it to do and there seems to be no other way to do it, so to me that is a code solution, not a hack.

I'm using the WPFBackgroundProgressIndicator open source project I downloaded from codeproject (I think) which has the option to show the busy indicator in the main content with or without a fade out, or as a popup and it runs as a background thread which is ideal and why I chose it.

The problem was that when you run a long running method, the code execution completes synchronously but all the binding OnPropertyChanged("") updates run asychronously and queue on the Dispatcher thread, so your work method completes before the WPF controls have a chance to call the Getters of the dependency properties, to retrieve the new value. What you need to do is effectively "block" until all the Dispatcher events have completed and that is why not everyone will like this solution as it "blocks", but then that is exactly what I am trying to do. I WANT to block the application until the full update has completed as I dont want the user to be able to do anything visually while data is still rendering, so that is my requirement. Clean blocking is preferable to messy interaction.

So the solution, believe it or not, is a single line of code just after the work method call. It is as follows.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

Which as you can see effectively queues a new task on the Dispatcher thread and blocks current code execution until it finishes, but as you give it the lowest priority, this call will wait until all OTHER dispatcher execution finishes, ie all rendering completes. Once render is complete, this line will be executed and you will exit with all rendering complete. The full method I have used it in context is below. I welcome your thoughts and discussion on this approach.

```
public void LongRunningTaskWithFade(BusyDecorator busy, Action longTask)
        {
            if (loading) return;
            loading = true;

            busy.FadeTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
            busy.IsBusyIndicatorShowing = true;

            // in order for setting the opacity to take effect, you have to delay the task slightly to ensure WPF has time to process the updated visual
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    longTask();
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    HideBusyDisplay(busy);                    
                }
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
```